# Need Help on Custom Labels

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF page where I need to display an error message using Custom Labels when the checkbox is not checked after hitting the save button. Can anyone help me how to use custom labels since I am using it for the first time...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference a Custom Label in Apex using `Label`:

```
if(!booleanVariableLinkedToCheckbox) {
  ApexPages.addMessage(
    new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.SEVERITY.ERROR,
      'Error Title',
      Label.ErrorMessage
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked...